# Process a CSV using PowerShell with different columns per row

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with no usable header row (the first row is information about the file, i.e. creation date).

There are set record types in the CSV file which are in the first column. i.e. column 1 could be PRA, ASA or POA.

Depending on the value of column 1 will determine what's in the rest of the fields. From this file I need to blank out all data that I'm not going to require for security before the file is sent out to a third-party. As we have different record types I can't do a simple loop and block out columns 3, 4 and 6 for example.

My plan was to go through the CSV line by line, look at the first column then output each record type to a separate file so they could be processed individually.

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter ~ -Encoding UTF8 -Path tinysample.dat | Foreach-Object {
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Name -eq 'HDR') {
            if ($($property.Value) -eq 'PRA' -OR $($property.Value) -eq 'POA') {
                Export-Csv -InputObject $_ -Append -Delimiter ~ -Encoding UTF8 -LiteralPath "$($property.Value).dat"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, the records are being output along with the header row which I don't want. I wanted to set my own header in each respective file which I can then use easily to determine which columns should be hidden.

Also some of the records are being truncated in the new CSV.

I was able to achieve this with bash using grep and awk and was hoping I'd be able to do the same with Powershell.

Comment: Using `Import-Csv` will apply headers (intrinsic or apllied ones) to all rows. So use Get-Content (or streamreader if speed is an issue) and get 1st column (via substring or RegEx) to switch the output file you wrote the header line initially .